# How to solve this equation? or get the numbers of solutions of the function?

Tags: equation-solving

I have a function like this..
$$
f[k]=\int_0^\infty Exp[-ax]x(Cos[bx])^{2}BesslJ[0,kx]dx
$$
I want to know how many local maximuns this function has..
So I try to get the derivative of f[k]
$$
g[k]=D[f[k],k];
$$
Then the result from mathematica is 
$$
g[k]=-6ka^{-4}(1+k^{2}/a^{2})^{-5/2}-3k(a-2ib)^{-4}(1+k^{2}/(a-2ib)^{2})^{-5/2}-3k(a+2ib)^{-4}(1+k^{2}/(a+2ib)^{2})^{-5/2},.
$$

I need to get the results 
$$
g[k]==0,k=??
$$
Because in the function there is a  & b,I use Solve..But it can't get the answer..Actually just the number of the solutions is necessary for me..
I am a beginner of the Mathematica..TKS in advance.

Comment: Please post the code for `f[x]`. LaTeX is fine for typesetting, but it's better to have actual code.

Comment: TKS for your suggestion..

Comment: One solution is `x = 0`.  I believe that there are two more.

Comment: YES..x=0 is one of the answer...But I need the exact numbers of this function...Any solutions?

Comment: Are `a` and `b` both real with `a > 0`?

Comment: YES. a & b both real and a>0..

Comment: Note that WLOG you can assume that $b=1$ by a change of variables. At that point, you get an expression in two variables $k$ and $a$. I'm still not sure if it's analytically solvable. Plotting the 2D plot of the inverse of its absolute value showed some interesting structure, though... I might post a partial answer in the morning.

Comment: Waiting for your answer..TKS so much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g[k]=0` is not easily simplified.  So, I plotted `g` (with `k` and `b` both scaled to `a`):

```
Manipulate[ Plot[g /. {a -> 1, b -> b0}, {k, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {-.01, .01}],
 {{b0, 1}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

A sample curve, for `b = 6.12`, is

[image: g at 6.12]

Manifestly, there are three zeros, one at `k = 0` and the others at positions dependent on `b`.  (The curve does not cross the axis at large k.)

**Addendum**

It also is instructive to plot `f` itself (again for `b = 6.12`)

[image: f at 6.12]

Thus, `f` has 2 maxima and one minimum.

Comment: YES..U R right..I plan to try Manipulate k&a&b before but mathematica can't give the answer..U assumed a→1(or maybe some others) and now it works. TKS so much.

Comment: Actually `a->1` is a renormalization without loss of generality.  Glad to be of help.